# Mod_rewrite redirect not working as intended (working in htaccess checker)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect users accessing **https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?p=home** to **https://www.mywebsite.com/**. I have already added the code below to my public_html's .htaccess file and have tested it on an [htaccess checker](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=e882c62b-4286-4a13-8cb5-61da851c3163).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=home$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Based on my code, do you have any idea why the redirect is not working even though the htaccess checker says it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following Rules in your htaccess rules file. Please don't trust htaccess checker sites they don't give correct results. Have your htaccess file with following rules and make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Redirection external rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?p=home\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
##Rewrite internal rule here.
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?p=home [L]
```

Comment: @neah panilag, could you please do let know if this has worked for you?